# Go not interpreting http request correctly

Tags: mongodb, go

I have a mongoDb instance connected and my request (from my React app) gets a 200 back. I can see the collection in Mondodb as "cats" with a record for each cat but the cat records looks like:

```
_id:5f66641bad25efa40b810d83 - fine
name:"" - should not be blank
favorite:false -should be true
```

I had had some cors problems at first so I changed what was "Content-Type" to "content-type" (for Access-Control-Allow-Headers) and that "fixed" the cors issue. I have no idea if that is what is breaking the code though.

Since this is my first time setting up a database on my own I am just not sure where I have broken the code. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my CreateCat method:

```
func CreateCat(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Context-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type")
    var cat models.Cat
    _ = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&cat)
    fmt.Println(cat)
    insertOneFavoriteCat(cat)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(cat)
}
```

Here is my model:

```
type Cat struct {
    ID          primitive.ObjectID `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Name        string             `json:"name,string"`
    Favorite    bool               `json:"favorite,string"`
}
```

This is what println prints: `{ false}`

and if you are curious if it's my frontend, this is the request getting sent:

```
{"cat":{"name":"tabby","favorite":true}}
```

Comment: You are setting Context-Type, not Content-Type

Comment: Don't ignore the error returned by Decode. You have to wrap your Cat type in a struct containing a Cat field. https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

Comment: @Peter While I absolutely agree with you OP shouldn't ignore **any error** in this case I believe error would be `<nil>` and won't save soul here as wrapping JSON object will be considered fitting into `Cat` (with no matched keys). I believe they get `{false}` because of `Favorite` field defined in `Cat` not being found in wrapping JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that JSON MongoDB returns doesn't match how your struct would be decoded. That `false` comes from `Favorite` field which cannot be found in JSON object with `cat` key returned by MongoDB. To decode this type of response you need to define a wrapping struct (as `CatModel` in my example below) because your `Cat` is not top level object but just a member key of upper level JSON object:

```json
type CatModel struct {
    Cat struct {
        ID       primitive.ObjectID `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
        Name     string `json:"name"`
        Favorite bool   `json:"favorite"`
    } `json:"cat"`
}
```

Also you have typo (`Context-Type` instead of `Content-Type`) in header name. Correct `Header().Set()` is:

```
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
```